# Fade out a CSS3 animation

Tags: jquery, css

The idea is to fade out **only** the animation itself, after you stop hovering the `.item` (not the entire item).

I've tried the following CSS:

```
.item{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-animation 1s;
    -webkit-animation: none;
}

.item:hover{
    -webkit-animation: party_nav_alt2 1s infinite linear;        
}

@-webkit-keyframes party_nav_alt2 {
    0% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px red;}
    20% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px yellow;}
    40% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px cyan;}
    60% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px #7700ff;}
    80% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px white;}
    100% {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px red;}
}
```

But it didn't work.

Solutions with jQuery are also welcome.

**EDIT**: The following is a demo to see what I mean. It does the effect but always fades out with a red color:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/Lz79P/2/)

**EDIT 2**: [This is the **effect**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/Lz79P/4/) that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I believe this is impossible without adding another element.

However if you are willing to add another (invisible) element, you could do [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz79P/3/), which toggles the opacity of an element the same size and position with the animating shadow on hover

```
.item{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;    
}
.animation {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-animation 1s linear ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    transition: all 0s ease-out;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:transparent;
    transition: all 1s ease-in; 
    -webkit-animation: party_nav_alt2 1s infinite linear;
    opacity:0;
}
.animation:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I did a few tweaks to that CSS and I found the effect I've been looking for. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure i understand the question, if you could post a jsfiddle or some more code that would be very helpful. But going what you've said i have an option which may be of interest using:

**A little Jquery**

```
$( ".item" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).fadeIn( 2000 );
});

$( ".item" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).fadeOut( 2000 );
});
```

"2000" being 2000ms which is equal to 2 seconds; you can adjust at your leisure.

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FW89m/)

**OR CSS**

```
.item {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
.item:hover {
    -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
    -moz-opacity: 0.25;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjf8c/)

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to fade out the object, only the CSS3 Animation. JsFiddle added!

Comment: To be honest i'm not sure that's possible. But your JSFiddle has made it clearer for anyone who would know. Best of luck !

Comment: Good to know! ...and sorry for my english. :P

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.item{
    transition: all 400ms ease-out; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.item:hover{
    transition: all 200ms ease-in; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px #7700ff;
    border: 2px solid #7700ff;
}
```

you can change the property as you need.

see this http://jsfiddle.net/FPLjM/

Comment: `opacity` is for the entire tag. I need to stop the animation after I stop hovering my mouse, fading out **only** the animation (for ie the  `box-shadow` animation I set up there, not the entire item).